# Cannot use stream deck with MS Teams - where to past API keys?

Tags: microsoft-teams, stream-deck

I own a stream deck and wanted to use it for my video conferences as well. In general, there is a [plugin](https://marketplace.elgato.com/product/microsoft-teams-da5e2bbc-197c-4afe-8a85-a9941bf52697) available, that should allow to integrate with the Teams application and trigger actions (like mute/unmute, raise/lower hand, reactions, ...).

I fond only some documentation, that hints to use some API keys provided by Teams. I found these in Teams but in the Stream Deck I find no place where I could paste the API key in order to register it.

Has anyone tried it and was able to run it successfully?

Does anyone have a clue where I might file a bug report or concrete questions wrt the stream deck plugin?